Не работаю миграции в docker-compose файле
Приветствую у меня выдаёт такую ошибку в логах
travel-expense-be-migrate-1  | error: dial tcp: lookup database on 127.0.0.11:53: server misbehaving
travel-expense-be-migrate-1 exited with code 1

А вот что у меня находится в docker-compose файле:
version: '3.8'

services:
go-app:
  build: .
  env_file:
    - .env
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
  command: go run cmd/main.go -b 0.0.0.0
db:
  image: postgres:alpine
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
migrate:
      image: migrate/migrate
      volumes:
        - .:/migrations
      command:
        [ "-path", "/migrations", "-database",  "postgres://ilya:gorm@database:5432/gin_web?sslmode=disable", "up" ]
volumes:
 postgres-db:

Вот мой Dockerfile:
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN go mod tidy

И я понять не могу как это исправить, смотрел ответы на этот вопрос, они присутствуют, но они не полноценны. Прошу, помогите решить эту проблему, второй день уже не могу разобраться.
